# PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, always returns empty results

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts

I'm trying to use a SearchView to query the contacts provider by phone number.

I'm using cursor loader to query the content provider

`case CONTACT_SEARCH_DEVICE_PHONE:
                String phoneNumber = args.getString(Constants.EXTRA_QUERY_PARAM);
                Uri uri =
                        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI
                                .buildUpon().appendPath(phoneNumber).build();
                return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null,
                        null, null, null);`

My problem is that the PhoneLookup always returns empty cursor, although If I wrote the same phone number inside the official android contacts application, I get the expected results.

If I used the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI instead of the PhoneLookup URI I get results but it is completely wrong and does not match the expected results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I'm trying this code in Lollipop

Comment: first try ContentResolver.query with your uri and see what it returns, make sure your uri is correct

Comment: Unfortunately tried Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("0")); then getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null) it didn't work, still returned an empty cursor.

Comment: Tried this URI content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/0114, still not results.

Comment: i will give you correct uri in one hour when im back home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74644/discussion-between-ahmed-i-khalil-and-pskink).

Comment: try ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Google's [recommended](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) method does not work as expected and always returns an empty cursor(perhaps I'm using it wrong).

Thanks to pskink, I got it working by using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` instead of `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`.